# "'Whatever word he says" or "whatever words he says"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> Do not believe whatever **word** he says.

Should ‘word’ be singular or plural after ‘whatever’?

Comment: Your sentence just doesn't sound quite right regardless of whether *word* is singular or plural. A more idiomatic way to say that would be this: *Do not believe a word he says.*

Answer (score 1):

A very good question!

Yes, as Michael says, the proper way to tell that sentence is...

> Don't believe a word he says.

OR

> Don't believe whatever he says

But to answer your question,

Yes, *whatever* is *singular* **and** *plural* both!

From COCA:

> We're running large deficits still. ***And whatever things*** that are using up those revenues are things not good for the U.S. Treasury. The Treasury will look for as many ways as they can to stop this. Whether it will be successful or whether Congress will step in a good question.

I also found a few biblical references (though it may be archaic then).

> *Finally, brothers, be considering these things— whatever things are true, whatever things are honorable, whatever things are right, whatever things are pure, whatever things are lovely, whatever things are commendable, if there is any virtue, and if there is any praise.*